# Getting System.StackOverFlowException with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

Bit of a weird one this. Checked everything in working last night and went to bed as you do. Now at this point I will mention I am a team of one and there is no one else working on this!

Got up this morning to pick up where I left of and now I get `System.StackOverFlow` exception in `ModelContainer.cs`. Absolutely nothing has changed from last night.

The Dev PC is Windows 11. Database server is Windows Server 2019 running SQL Server 2022. Visual Studio 2022. Everything is fully patched to the latest versions.

This is the call I am making to the API:

[image]

A screenshot showing exactly where the error is thrown:

[image]

And this is the code for the thing I am calling (the GET) :

```
namespace Phoenix.Server.Web.Api.Base.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController 
    {
        private AccountService _accountService = new AccountService();

        // GET api/account
        public string Get()
        {
            return "The beast is alive!!";
        }

        // POST api/account/create
        [Route("create")]
        public string Create([FromBody] AccountCreationFullRequest request)
        {
            return _accountService.CreateAccount(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Text version of the model as requested:

```
public partial class ModelContainer : DbContext
{
    public ModelContainer()
        : base("name=ModelContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AppSetting> AppSettings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<County> Counties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DatabaseVersion> DatabaseVersions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DocumentData> DocumentDatas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DocumentIndex> DocumentIndexes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DocumentType> DocumentTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EventLog> EventLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EventSource> EventSources { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EventType> EventTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Pepper> Peppers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PostalAddress> PostalAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Salt> Salts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TelephoneNumber> TelephoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserSession> UserSessions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UsersToPassword> UsersToPasswords { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Last night the beast was alive - this morning its seems to have had a heart attack!

Any help greatly appreciated - there isn't enough coffee in the world for this madness on a Sunday

Comment: post code as text please.

Comment: The point of the image is to show exactly the position the error is thrown - cant do that in text

Comment: somewhere at some place you are calling something infinitely

Comment: The puzzling thing is that I wasnt last night when I finished - it was working fine.  I havent changed anything so far today

Comment: I request you to please provide the text version of the ModelContainer class. otherwise, I cant help. sorry

Comment: @VivekNuna - ah - ok.  I understand you now.  Give me a moment or two

Comment: Is your actual database called `ModelContainer` or something else? You call the `DbContext` constructor with that as your database name or a connection string.

Comment: @TimothyG.  The model container code you can see is auto generated by the wizard and is the "code behind" of the EDMX file.  In the the same library  is an app.config is a connections string that is placed in it by the creation of the EDMX file that takes it settings from the relevant selected database connection in the servers view.  This was all fine last night ( having worked on large teams I got into the habit of making sure I didnt check in code that broke builds).  This is also exactly how I have done it many times in the past.  this issue has never occurred for me before.

Comment: The call I am making to the controller quite literally does this - return " The beast is alive!".  It doesnt make any database calls at all

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your throw in the OnModelCreating. On a hunch if your project has something like an exception handler that uses anything like a logging method or such that tries to read or write to the DbContext and your connection string got out of line and was set up that it could try to create the schema since you mention EDMX I'm assuming this is EF6 which is less explicit about doing things like Code First creation. Beyond that set a junk Debug line and  breakpoint in your DbContext constructor and look at the call stack which might reveal a loop of calls you can trace back through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check a few things here. You may have not realised it yesterday but there will be an issue before as well if you have not made any code changes.

- You have to put breakouts and debug your code.
- Review your code and see if there are any loops running infinitely.
- You also need to check your recursive calls as well in your project.
- You also need to verify whether there are any circular dependencies
  or recursive relationships (or self-referencing relationships) within
  your entity classes in your database configuration.
- I am not sure but you can try commenting on this line  `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`
- I would also suggest commenting on a line one by one in your
  `ModelContainer`  for entities and checking which entity is causing
  this issue.
  You also need to make sure that you have not accidentally deleted anything from the database.
  Read the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=net-7.0), you might get some idea of the root cause.

Comment: Thank you.  I may be some time.  Ill let you know the result.  By the way I have breaks on every method and every error trap and none get tripped.  And the call itself I am making literally just returns the string "The beast is alive!"

Comment: Apologies for the delay getting back.  Not been too good.  Anyhow.  traced the problem to a redundant connection string in the web.config in the API.  There was a typo (one letter out) that had been corrected and checked back in but doesn't look like it took.  The end result was 2 different connections strings, one with the model and one in the web config.  Once again thank you everyone for your help - it is appreciated